# How to show element based on condition using ng-hide and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, categorical-data, ng-hide

I am using AngularJS and I have a table of items that I want to be able to display based on their color. For example, if I click on the "SHOW GREEN" and "SHOW RED" checkboxes, the table will show only the items that are green or red.

This is the item object:

```
{"name":"Fire Truck", "color":"red"}
```

Here are my checkboxes, which when clicked will evaluate to TRUE or FALSE:

```
<select id="item_color" ng-model='color'>
   <option value='green'>SHOW GREEN</option>
   <option value='red'>SHOW RED</option>
   <option value='blue'>SHOW BLUE</option>
</select>
```

And here is my table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide='???'>
   <td>{{item.name}} </td>
   <td>{{item.color}} </td>
</tr>
```

So how can I have my table dynamically show the desired items?
The ideal solution would also allow me to list 3 seperate tables for all items of each color. I am little stumped on how to go about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide='item.color !== color'>
   <td>{{item.name}} </td>
   <td>{{item.color}} </td>
</tr>
```

It's that simple. Alternatively, use `ng-if` to not stamp out the inverse at all:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if='item.color === color'>
   <td>{{item.name}} </td>
   <td>{{item.color}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So would I be able to use multiple conditions inside the ng-hide directive? So that I could display both red and yellow? Or is it possible to define the variable color to have multiple colors?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Antiga for his solution. I went for something similar using a controller function inside ng-hide. This works for 3+ conditions.

```
<!-- Checkboxes to toggle T/F which colors to show -->
<input type='checkbox' id='full' ng-model='toggle_red'>RED
<input type='checkbox' id='part' ng-model='toggle_green'>GREEN
<input type='checkbox' id='former' ng-model='toggle_blue'>BLUE

<!-- ng-hide will show item if color_hider() evals to false -->
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide='color_hider(item.color)'>
   <td>{{item.name}} </td>
   <td>{{item.color}} </td>
</tr>

<script>
// variables for the toggles
$scope.toggle_red = true;
$scope.toggle_green = true;
$scope.toggle_blue = true; 

// evals to false for each color if both conditions are true
$scope.color_hider(color){
    if(color == 'red' && $scope.toggle_red === true){ 
        return false;
    }else if(color == 'green' && $scope.toggle_green === true){
        return false;
    }else if(color == 'blue' && $scope.toggle_blue === true){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    };
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ng-repeating over the entire collection and then hiding individual elements, it might be better to filter the `ng-repeat` itself:

`<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{'color': 'green'}">`

will ng-repeat over all items whose color is green.

(For more complex conditions you can use a function as a filter instead: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)